# Need help loading all application users

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I am learning how to do MVC with entity framework and have ran into a problem.  And i may be going about users wrong but i think this is the way.

I have expanded fields for my users

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
[Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have a page where i am wanting to create a company user and on that page you select an Application User from a drop down list.  This is from my controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.CompanyID = new SelectList(db.Companies, "CompanyID", "CompanyName");
            ViewBag.CompanyRoleID = new SelectList(db.CompanyRoles, "CompanyRoleID", "Description");
            ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(db.Users, "UserName", "FirstName");
            return View();
        }
```

There are two issues with doing this.  When i create my controller.  It wants to add this line to the Identity Controller:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<PropertyManager.Models.ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
```

And when i go to that page, the ddl is never filled.  I can do a db.Users.ToList() and see there is objects in it, but it never fills my ddl. Here is the front end code:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, "UserName", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Users", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

This has become a huge annoyance because it puts me in a spot where i can not continue with the development because i can't create the things i need.  Can someone help me, or tell me if i am going the wrong direction using this?  I have always done custom application user creation and this is the first i've used the membership/identity stuff.

Comment: You need to get the UserStore from the correct place.  Are you using the modern ASP.NET with OWin or are using some other identity provider?  Are you using dependency injection?

Comment: I am using the modern ASP.NET with OWin. And i just figured out why the ddl wasn't populating. The first name wasn't filled in so it wasn't even creating an empty line item. But i'm noticing that it is not filling in the UserName so when i actually try to create it, the HTTPPost is not getting back a username and failing.

Comment: Well finally figured that part out, the ViewBag item needed to be named UserName also.